# Using Array inside a function in angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-template

I am learning angular 4 and tried making a simple application.

However, One place where I am stuck is that in `AppComponent` **class**. I have an array, which gets populated when, in the browser, I enter text click add button, the text gets added in the array. Now when I click the submit button, I want to see the array in the console.

here is my appComponent code :

```
    items = [];
    newItem= "";
    convertJSON= function(items){
      var arr= items;
      console.log(arr);
    }
```

So what I am doing here is that with help of another **function**.

I am populating the array "**Items**" on **button** click. Now when I click another button I want those **array** elements to be used inside convertJSON function and display it in the console.

In JS we can use a **global** array but here when I am doing like this "**undefine**" is showing up in my console.

Comment: You should also show us how you call the `convertJSON` method. Do you pass the `items` as parameter there?

Comment: Ya right. That's what was missing from my end. Thank you. The parameter wasn't passed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into problem with [shadowing instance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `items` with local function parameter `items`. Depends on how you call the method (with the parameter or without).

Try to rename the function parameter to something else:

```
items = [];

convertJSON = function(arr){
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Or if you do not pass that parameter to `convertJSON` at all, just omit that:

```
items = [];

convertJSON = function(){
  console.log(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's certainly due to a missing param or variable shadowing when using function(). in your case you should use a class variable items = [] and create a separate function convertJSON().

```
items = [];

addButton($event) {
    this.items.push($event.value);
}

submit() {
  convertJSON(this.items);
}

convertJSON(array) {
    console.log(array);
}
```